# UIScrollView with "inertia" but paged.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an horizontal `UIScrollView`, I need this scrollview to be paged. But the problem is that I also need the "inertia" effect of a non paged `UIScrollView`. I've been googling and stackoverflowing for a while and no luck at all.

Any idea or clue so I can start reading on how to perform this task?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want it to work? If you swipe really fast, do you want it to scroll for a while, without stopping at the next page?

Comment: exactly that, but when it stops I want it to stop in a page.

Comment: It's easy enough to do something like that, but it can take some effort to make it feel right. I think you'd need to override, completely or partially, the deceleration curve, so it stops where you want it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If paging is disabled, the scroll view will call your delegate when dragging ends. Using the `-scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` method (iOS 5 and later), you can determine the inertia-based target, and change the value passed in to modify it. For example, this code in your delegate will change the target so that the scroll view will automatically decelerate to a multiple of its bounds size.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    CGSize pageSize = scrollView.bounds.size;
    targetContentOffset->x = pageSize.width *
        round(targetContentOffset->x / pageSize.width);
    targetContentOffset->y = pageSize.height *
        round(targetContentOffset->y / pageSize.height);
}
```

Comment: The only way to show you my gratitude is saying: "I LOVE YOU". This worked perfectly fine, I was thinking of doing something way more difficult!! THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a solution using the scrollViewDelegate method: scrollViewDidScroll. In the method I'm checking the velocity and applying paging only if the scroll speed is less than a certain value, so it will keep the inertia. I don't use the normal paging of UIScrollView but calling the setContentOffset method instead so I can apply the paging at the right time. The code might look overly complicated but you could probably divide it into smaller methods and make it look nicer. Play around with the two constants and see what works best. Hope it helped you in the right direction at least.

Mattias

```
#define SPEED_MIN = 2
#define SPEED_MAX = 10

{
    CGFloat prevX;
    BOOL dragging;
    NSInteger page;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat nextX = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat speedX = nextX - prevX;
    speedX = (speedX < 0 ? -speedX : speedX);
    prevX = nextX;

    if (dragging)
    {
        if (speedX < SPEED_MIN && page < 0)
        {
            page = [self getClosestPage:scrollView];
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(page * scrollView.frame.size.width, 0) animated:YES];
            [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
        }
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == page * scrollView.frame.size.width)
        {
            page = -1;
            dragging = false;
            [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dragging = speedX > SPEED_MAX;
    }
}
- (NSInteger)getClosestPage:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat x = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat w = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger nbrOfPages = scrollView.contentSize.width / w;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbrOfPages; i++) {
        CGFloat dx1 = x - i*w;
        CGFloat dx2 = (i+1)*w - x;
        if (dx1 > 0 && dx2 > 0) {
            if (dx1 >= dx2) {
                return i;
            } else {
                return (i+1 < nbrOfPages ? i+1 : i);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```